# Windows 7 / IE9 - how to block all sites except few?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, blocking

I'm setting up a PC for a 5-year-old. I want to allow access to the Internet to a handful of sites only.

- Tried IE Content Advisor, but it doesn't support blocking all (or I missed something)
- I tried the proxy method, where you set a fake proxy and make the required sites to bypass proxy. I don't like this method as it blocks whatever other software that uses IE settings.
- No such option in Windows 7 parental control
- BullGuard's parental control, has options to trust a site, but doesn't block all except few.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft Family Safety](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/essentials-other-programs?T1=t3) (part of the Live Essentials suite) has this feature. You can BLOCK ALL except for the list of sites that you maintain.

To enable this feature:

- select the user in question
- go to Web Filtering
- turn on web filtering
- move the slider all the way up to "Allow List Only"

Separately you can maintain the list of sites that you allow in "Web Filtering Lists".

Comment: may be k9 will do either: `http://www1.k9webprotection.com/`

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this one for IE only here:
http://www.iishacks.com/2009/03/12/using-the-ie-content-advisor-to-block-all-internet-access/

> 1. Copy the following text into Notepad and save it as “**noaccess.rat**” in the **Windows\system32** directory (or another directory of your choice). Be sure that the file extension is **.rat** and not .txt. You can download a zip file containing [noaccess.rat here](http://www.iishacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/noaccessrat.zip).
>
>    ```
>    ((PICS-version 1.0)
>     (rating-system “http://www.microsoft.com”)
>     (rating-service “http://www.microsoft.com”)
>     (name “Noaccess”)
>     (description “This file will block all sites.”)
>
>     (category
>      (transmit-as “m”)
>      (name “Yes”)
>      (label
>       (name “Level 0: No Setting”)
>       (description “No Setting”)
>       (value 0))
>      (label
>       (name “Level 1: No Setting”)
>       (description “No Setting”)
>       (value 1))))
>    ```
> 2. In the “**Control Panel**” double-click on “**Internet Options**” and click on the “**Content**” tab. If in Internet Explorer, click on “**Tools**” and “**Internet Options**” and click on the “**Content**” tab.
> 3. Click “**Enable**.”
> 4. Inside the “**General**” tab click on “**Rating System**.”
> 5. Remove all entries and click “**Add**.” Add “**noaccess.rat**” from the **Windows\system32** directory.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Click on the “**Approved Sites**” tab and add all the websites you wish to allow access to.
>
>    [image]

Also, remember to tick off the box on Content Advisor -> General -> "Users can see websites that have no rating." Obviously other browsers will ignore these settings, but in my case I did use Parental Controls to avoid this.

Comment: I have problems with this. IE behaves very strange with redirects. Do you know of any known problems? As soon as I turn it off everything goes back to normal.